# What is the purpose of the delegates are immutable in c#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I was reading a book illustrated C # 2012 in the section Combining Delegates point not notice that? Purpose of the delegates are immutable.

> Combining Delegates 
>   All the delegates you’ve seen so far have had only
>   a single method in their invocation lists. Delegates can be “combined”
>   by using the addition operator. The result of the operation is the
>   creation of a new delegate, with an invocation list that is the
>   concatenation of copies of the invocation lists of the two operand
>   delegates. For example, the following code creates three delegates.
>   The third delegate is created from the combination of the first two.

```
MyDel delA = myInstObj.MyM1;
MyDel delB = SClass.OtherM2;
MyDel delC = delA + delB; // Has combined invocation list
```

> Although the term combining delegates might give the impression that
>   the operand delegates are modified, they are not changed at all. In
>   fact, delegates are immutable. After a delegate object is created, it
>   cannot be changed. Figure 15-6 illustrates the results of the
>   preceding code. Notice that the operand delegates remain unchanged.

[image]

Comment: Delegates are actually method pointers. What would you suggest mutating such a delegate do? Modify the underlying method?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well, probably OP might think that they could be mutable so the addition of two delegates reuses one of the delegates' instance and adds a delegate to the invocation list... who knows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thread-safety and speed are the primary concerns here.  A delegate update is not atomic, it requires updating 6 fields and a list.  Making it atomic so it cannot get corrupted requires a lock, far too expensive for such a basic operation that rarely *needs* to be thread-safe.

By making it immutable, the delegate object cannot get corrupted since it always sets fields on an object that nobody has a reference to yet.  Reassigning the delegate object reference is atomic, a basic .NET memory model guarantee.  So no need for a lock anymore.  The trade-off is less efficient memory use, it is a small penalty.

Do keep in mind that the thread-safe delegate update does not automatically make your code thread-safe as well.  The test-and-fire code needs to copy the reference to avoid NRE and you can make a callback to a method that was already unsubscribed.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are pointers to a method, either concrete or anonymous (*well, even anonymous methods are compiled with some compiler-generated identifier*).

Would be reasonable that something that points to some concrete thing be *mutable*? I don't think so. Each instance represents a pointer to some method. Do you want to point to some other method? Create a new pointer. That is, you instantiate a new delegate.

In the other hand, the addition of two or more delegates has this result because [`+` operator can be overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx). That is, delegates can be part of an addition but internally `+`'s overload is creating a new delegate with an invocation list.