# Are all event handlers always called when unsubscribing other handlers within a handler?

Tags: c#, events

I wrote a test that shows that when invoking an event, all handlers are called even though one of the handlers (not the last one) unsubscribe all the handlers.

The test is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cmeeren/6c153ff09c97fb3f5d9225f71ddce4a1), repeated below.

My question is: Is this behavior expected and documented (I haven't found any mention of it), and can it be counted on? Or is it perhaps just due to some peculiarities of how I've written the test?

```
namespace EventUnsubscriptionTest
{
    using System;

    using NUnit.Framework;

    public class EventSource
    {
        public event Action Event;

        public void TriggerEvent()
        {
            this.Event?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public class EventSourceTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void When_Unsubscribing_Should_InvokeAllBeforeUnsubscribing()
        {
            // Arrange
            var invokeCounter = 0;
            var listener1InvokedOrder = 0;
            var listener2InvokedOrder = 0;
            var listener3InvokedOrder = 0;

            var sut = new EventSource();

            Action listener1 = null;
            Action listener2 = null;
            Action listener3 = null;

            listener1 = () => listener1InvokedOrder = ++invokeCounter;
            listener2 = () =>
            {
                listener2InvokedOrder = ++invokeCounter;
                sut.Event -= listener1;
                sut.Event -= listener2;
                sut.Event -= listener3;
            };

            listener3 = () => listener3InvokedOrder = ++invokeCounter;

            sut.Event += listener1;
            sut.Event += listener2;
            sut.Event += listener3;

            // Act
            sut.TriggerEvent();

            // Assert
            Assert.That(listener1InvokedOrder, Is.EqualTo(1));
            Assert.That(listener2InvokedOrder, Is.EqualTo(2));
            Assert.That(listener3InvokedOrder, Is.EqualTo(3));

            // Ensure that we actually unsubscribed
            sut.TriggerEvent();
            Assert.That(invokeCounter, Is.EqualTo(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior, because multicast delegates are immutable.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Delegates are immutable; once created, the invocation list of a delegate does not change.

Thus, any ongoing invocation of the multicast delegate (event handlers) will not be affected by subscriptions and unsubscriptions in the delegates (or generally between calling the first and last delegates). All handlers at the time of `Invoke()` will get called (barring any thrown exceptions in the handlers). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35969564/2978652).

Answer (score 0):

> My my question is: Is this behavior expected and documented (I haven't found any mention of it), and can it be counted on?

Yes, because you are triggering all 3 listeners *before* unsubscribing them.

This first line

```
// Act
sut.TriggerEvent();
```

is what is causing their execution and so they will be invoked before the second listener unsubscribes them

Comment: It seems to me that this relies on an implementation detail. Your description (that `sut.TriggerEvent()` is causing their execution) does not in itself indicate that the invocation does *not* simply iterate through the list of delegates, and that the delegate list may be modified while iterating. (I might have misunderstood something fundamental; if so, I'm sorry, and please clarify for me.)

Comment: no, you haven't misunderstood. So let's put it differently, according to your wording. Also if the invocation simply iterates through the list, I'm saying that this loop is predefined before the unsubscribing events, so it will go on calling all of them anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Could you add to the answer some source for your claim, or alternatively an explanation for why this is obvious/self-evident?

Comment: I found the key piece of knowledge here: multicast delegates are immutable. I added it as an answer. Thanks for your answer/comments, though!

Comment: Better source here from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx): "*Delegates are immutable; once created, the invocation list of a delegate does not change.*" and more elaborated SO answer about the reasons [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968889/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-delegates-are-immutable-in-c)